# Java WebServices - how to call service?

Tags: java, web-services

I am wondering how I can call webservice from URL for the following Hello World example:

```
package example;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.xml.ws.Endpoint;


@WebService()
public class HelloWorld {
  @WebMethod
  public String sayHelloWorldFrom(String from) {
    String result = "Hello, world, from " + from;
    System.out.println(result);
    return result;
  }
  public static void main(String[] argv) {
    Object implementor = new HelloWorld ();
    String address = "http://localhost:9000/HelloWorld";
    Endpoint.publish(address, implementor);
  }
}
```

I've been trying the following:

```
localhost:9000/HelloWorld/sayHelloWorldFrom?from=me
```

But this doesnt print anything in my console.

Comment: For Web Service, it is actually a web interface use HTTP protocol. So basically should use HTTP request to fire a service request and use HTTP response to get their answers. You could imagine how many way you could achieve this, either by using basic Java HTTP call or apache httpclient or even Spring resttemplate.

Comment: So, correct me if I am wrong, there is no way to make that call from URL?

Comment: Yes you could. Just fire HTTP request from any available ways you could find, including those 3 things I mentioned in above.

Answer (score 0):

Few things to consider based on the information you have provided:
1. deploy the web service on tomcat or glass fish or other application server
2. split out that code into service and client

further reading here: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnayn.html